# tangent plane of function not in the form $z=f(x,y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to find the equation of the tangent plane to $x=y^2+2z^2-124$ at $(8, -10, -4)$

I subtracted x from both sides and let that expression define $f(x,y,z)$. Then I applied the formula of a tangent plane at a point, which gave me $4+2y(y+10)+4z(z+4)$, but this doesn't make sense since it is not linear.

The only other idea I have is to solve for $z$ and do the same thing, but the problem with that is it would include $\pm$

Comment: Surface equation $f(x,y,z)=0$

Differential form: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz=0$

Tangent plane: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}|_{P_0}(x-x_0)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}|_{P_0}(y-y_0)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}|_{P_0}(z-z_0)=0$

Comment: Other way: If you know how to find tangent plane for $z(x,y)$ then you can use this method for $x(y,z)$ just changing your arguments.

Comment: thanks, if you submit either one as an answer i'll accept it